# Retrieve attachment from list help

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

```
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {      

            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListSelectCategory.SelectedItem.Value);

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
              HyperLink hp =new HyperLink();
              // want to display attachent here like hyperlink how do i do that= , i only want to have one attachment for every uploaded attachment
              //Example
              //Name:Simon
              //Age:25
              //Attachment: hello.jpg

              //Name:Arnold
              //Age:25
              //Attachment:jebiga.jpg
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below function....

just pass SPListItem object to below function, it returns attachment url from list item.

```
//set attachment url to hyperlink..
hyperlink.Text = "attachment name find from returned attachment url";
hyperlink.NavigateUrl = GetAttachmentUrls(objSPListItem)

private string GetAttachmentUrls(SPListItem oItem)
{

    string path = string.Empty;

    try

    {

        path = (from string file in oItem.Attachments
                          orderby file
                          select SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(oItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix, file)).FirstOrDefault();
        return path;
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

}
```

Comment: private string GetAttachmentUrls(SPListItem oItem){
 string path;try{
path = (from string file in oItem.Attachments
orderby file
select SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(oItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix, file)).FirstOrDefault();
return path;}
catch{
return string.Empty;
}}

Comment: if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){
HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items){
foreach (string currentAttachmentUrl in item.Attachments)
{
if (GetAttachmentUrls.Contains(currentAttachmentUrl))
 {
hp = new HyperLink();
hp.ID = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
hp.Text = item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + currentAttachmentUrl;
hp.NavigateUrl = currentAttachmentUrl;
GetAttachmentUrls.Add(currentAttachmentUrl);

Comment: i get red at if (GetAttachmentsurls.Contains and Getattachmentsurls.add